# ¿Cómo dividir por lotes la respuesta de un método get?

Tags: c#, json, api, rest, visual-studio-2017

estoy comenzando a desarrollar API REST en Visual Studio 2017, trabajo con BD existentes muy pobladas y cuando realizo una llamada GET a una tabla para listar todos los elementos se demora mucho, más de 1minuto en ocasiones porque tiene miles de filas. 
Necesito poder dividir en lotes la respuesta a esa consulta para cuando sea consumida no demore tanto (Json), de no ser posible dividir en el momento de obtenerla al menos poder dividirla cuando se ofrezca como servicio. Puede ser por un parámetro variable.
Gracias.

Comment: revisa tu modelo de bbdd, quizas solo con hacer indices correctos puedas solucionar el tema. En caso de un GET, puede ser mas importante que hagas un filtro por distintos valores.

Comment: incluso dentro de un filtro, por ejmplo "tipo de mensaje" en una tabla "cola de entrada" ya estoy limitando bastante pero siguen siendo cientos, necesito algo más concreto, algo de código.

Comment: has revisado los indices de tus tablas?

Comment: Hola Carlos. Miles de filas en una tabla no deben ser problema para un motor de BD. En definitiva puede ser un problema de tu modelo o índices para recuperar la información. Como comenta @Jakala , debes revisar tus índices para determinar si cuentas con los necesarios para recuperar la información de manera eficiente.

Comment: que es muy poblada? que intentaste? a que te referis con filtros? las bases estan correctas y tienen los indices correctos? que tipo de consultas intentas? cuantos elementos esta devolviendo? asi como esta, como que la pregunta es demasiado amplia no?

Comment: Independientemente de la demora, necesito dividir la respuesta, no darle a quien consuma el servicio un request tan largo

Comment: Normalmente la respuesta debe tener un indice o campo que se retorne de forma ordenada, adicional un indicador de cual fue el último registro retornado, el servicio GET debe tener un parametro de entrada que indique el último registro retornado y en esa consulta retorna apartir de ese registro.

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que los where que pones en tus consulta, que supongo que se los pasas en el get, que  por ejemplo where campo=23, campo sea un indice.
No se como es tu sistema, pero quiza la division deberias hacerla en el front, por ejemplo oblligar al usuario a realizar una seleccion parcial de los datos, con algun combo, radio button etc...
Saludos...